# WCF hosting issue in Chat Application

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I Have a scenario of chat application. A server and two client. Since I'm a newbie to WCF, I was wondering how to host this service so the client will only interact with the service via internet. In other words when a message is sent it will journey with internet to get to the service and from there it will go to the other client.

Comment: You will have to use Duplex channels to enable two-way communication.  Otherwise you will have to implement a polling mechanism on the clients (not very efficient usage of client or servers bandwidth).  Take a look at this article for some ideas: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/06/16/pushing-data-to-a-silverlight-client-with-wcf-duplex-service-part-i.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console, Windows service , asp.net with IIS no matter... as soon as the port is enable and the server machine is reachable from the internet it will work. After that is your own choice.

Answer (score 0):

No magic, just expose the service to the Internet.  You use the same methodology as you would to expose a website to the internet.   Host it on a public IP address and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks mate but if i understand correctly I need to host it only in IIS, right?

Comment: Not true.  That's probably the quickest and easiest way, but there's no reason you couldn't code your own host (which would likely run from a Windows Service).

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call it the easiest way ;).  @FidElio a WCF service is basically a socket server (under all the fancy wraps) so all you need is some container to host the service.  That container can be IIS, a console executable, the service control manager (NT Service), etc...  The point is all you need is an open port and the service has to stay running.  There are many ways to accomplish that besides using IIS.